# Is the SharePoint 2013 REST API fully supported in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Is the [SharePoint 2013 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) fully supported in SharePoint Online (part of Office 365)?

Assuming I have access permissions to make REST API calls to a SharePoint subscriptions, can I safely assume that all SP2013 REST URLs and resources are available to me?

PS - I know of one example where SharePoint has functionality missing in the SharePoint 2013 API - [The OData $batch query option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx). I'm interested in the opposite direction where SP2013 services might be missing in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can access all SharePoint 2013 rest urls and resources from your SP online tenant.

Basically OData query does not support for URL field query. Also Microsoft releases a new  framework, which supports all SharePoint operations. See this too:
[SharePoint Framework](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Comment: I would also recommend looking at the [SharePoint PnP-JS](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) framework. It allows the developer to access the REST api in a much simpler way.